# What were the names given to countries like Mesopotamia, Egypt (ancient) at the time of the Mahabharatha war?

Tags: mahabharata

Are there any writings which give the names of ancient countries like Egypt and Mesopotamia at the time of Mahabharata war?

Comment: idk about those in particular.. but since you said 'countries *like*' - Turkey is Turushka, Greece - Yavana, Afghanistan(Khandahar) - Gandhara, Kazhakstan/Krygystan - Kekeya etc. Generally, people outside Bharata desha were referred to as Mlecchas.

Comment: @ram  ancient Turkey was called Cannanite region, Greece was not evolved during Maha Bharat period and Mlecchas and Pishaacas were those people who  adhered to old customs of Rig Veda and not followed new Brahminical ethics. Look in Manu Smriti, these area covers present Uttarakhand state and West of Kashmir.

Answer (score 1):

Scholars place Maha Bharata war around 3000 BCE. At that time Mesopotamia was known as Sumer with two important cities Ur and Uma  quite frequently mentioned in Rig Veda. For example RV.4.58.1 - '*samudrAt ur mir madh umA ut Arat up AshunA sam amritatvam Anat*- at the end of the sea Ur is first, UmA in the middle, there they traded, took shelter and food; these were like life sustaining elements for trader{Anat}.

At that period Sumerian called Egypt as 'Magan' - again a name of very important Rig Vedic tribe -'Magh'. Indra is often referred as 'Maghvan' meaning the lord of 'Magh'. And the same Magh who migrated eastward to form the ancient country of 'Magadh' in Bihar.

Comment: @Bhaskar, Can you provide a translation link for the Rig verse which you have provided? Since I'm not confident with this translation. Pls check this  - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc832852.html#:~:text=%E2%80%9CThe%20sweet%20water%20swells%20up,%2C%20the%20navel%20of%20ambrosia.%E2%80%9D